# Upload CSV File with Jquery/Ajax and Cake PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, csv, file-upload

I have problems with posting the *temp_file* path to my cakephp controller.

At the moment, it works when i post it in the form tag:

```
<form id="ff" action="inputData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>W&auml;hlen Sie eine Textdatei (txt, html usw.) von Ihrem Rechner aus:<br>
        <input id="Datei" name="data[Excel][File]" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="text/*">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
        </p>
</form>
```

And with this in the controller:

```
else if (!empty($this->data) && is_uploaded_file($this->data['Excel']['File']['tmp_name'])) {
            $this->importData($this->data['Excel']['File']['tmp_name']);
            $excel=new Excel();
            $values=$excel->getParams($this->data['Excel']['File']['tmp_name']);
            exit;
        }
```

My aim is to do the post like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").click(function(){
        var data = $("#ff");
        $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/project/wpts/add",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: data,
                contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(csvarray){ 
                    alert(csvarray);
                    //set some variables
                }});

    });
});
```

Now my problem is, that I dont know, how I get the temp path of the file. 
How must the post looks like and how can I get the path in the controller?

Please help me. I search now two days for this problem, but I cant find anything usable.

Thanks.

Comment: file uploading cannot (as far as I'm aware) be doing using the jquery short ajax function instead you have to manually do an XHR request to perform the file upload.  The way I do it is I do the normal form submit data with a $.ajax and I do the file upload separate (so uploading a file doesn't hang the UI and user can carry on while upload happens in background) XHR to upload the file triggered by the success of the ajax request.

Comment: You need a plugin for this (example: https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file )

Comment: can you explain me, what the difference between the post request in the form element to the ajax post request is?
I want, that the user can select the file in the view, then i want to update it in cake, and return an array, which set some fields.
I dont understand why i need a plugin when the normal request is able to do that??

Comment: Dave, can you post the code for a seperate file upload?